# How to solve the date comparison issue in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date, comparison

I am using the following way to compare two dates:

```
if CONVERT(varchar(20), @ScheduleDate, 101) >= CONVERT(varchar(20), @CurrentDateTime, 101)
```

This is working fine for the current year, but when the comes in yearly like one date is `12/31/2012` and `1/1/2013` then its not working.

Please help me how can I resolve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

why do you comparing strings?
you can compare dates

```
if @ScheduleDate >= @CurrentDateTime
```

but if your date contains time, I usually do

```
if convert(nvarchar(8), @ScheduleDate, 112) >= convert(nvarchar(8), @CurrentDateTime, 112)
```

112 datetime format is YYYYMMDD so it's good for compare dates

Comment: Or just cast the `DATETIME` to `DATE` ..... `IF CAST(@ScheduleDate AS DATE) >= CAST(@CurrentDateTime AS DATE) .....`

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that string comparison is from left to right, so "1/...." is smaller than "12/...".

You need to use DATETIME comparisons, not string comparison.

Something like

```
DECLARE @ScheduleDate DATETIME = '1/1/2013',
        @CurrentDateTime DATETIME = '12/31/2012'

IF (@ScheduleDate >= @CurrentDateTime)
BEGIN
    SELECT @ScheduleDate, @CurrentDateTime
END

DECLARE @ScheduleDateString VARCHAR(20) = '1/1/2013',
        @CurrentDateTimeString VARCHAR(20) = '12/31/2012'
IF (CONVERT(DATETIME,@ScheduleDateString,101)>=CONVERT(DATETIME,@CurrentDateTimeString,101))
BEGIN
    SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,@ScheduleDateString,101),CONVERT(DATETIME,@CurrentDateTimeString,101)
END
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6638)

Note that if the variables are already datetimes, you do not need to convert them.

Comment: Is there any reason to convert the variables to DateTime if they are already DateTime?

Comment: @Greg, no, I have just added that to the answer.

Comment: i have compared only dates by that... if i am converting to datetime its taking time too

Comment: Then convert it to the DATE data type rather http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both variables are currently DateTime variables, can't you just compare them without converting to strings?

```
declare @ScheduleDate DATETIME, @CurrentDateTime DATETIME


SET @ScheduleDate = '1 Jan 2013'
SET @CurrentDateTime = GetDate()

IF (@ScheduleDate >= @CurrentDateTime)
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Do Something'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Do Something Else'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use CONVERT(nvarchar(8), @ScheduleDate, 112) function it's return string instead of date.

so,
Use "112" DateFormat in Sql Server it's return string in "YMD" format without any sepration.
compare that string in your query and get desire output.

Such as "if CONVERT(nvarchar(8), @ScheduleDate, 112) >= CONVERT(nvarchar(8), @CurrentDateTime, 112)"

Answer (score 0):

I would not use CONVERT to compare formatted strings. It is slow (well, more like microseconds, but still)

I use a UDF for SQL prior to version 2008

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[DateOnly] (@Date DateTime)  
RETURNS Datetime AS  
BEGIN 
  Return cast (floor (cast (@Date as float)) as DateTime)
END
```

and for versions >=2008 this approach

select convert(@MyDateTime as DATE)

Of course, you can compare datetime values directly, but to know whether two datetime values are on the same date (ignoring the time component), the above versions have proven to be effectivy.

Answer (score 0):

Date : From and To with following format

## from_Date# = #dateformat("#form.from#", "mm/dd/yyyy")

## to_Date#   = #dateformat("#now()#" + 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")

In SQL Statement
WHERE  a.DateCreated   >= CAST ('#from_date#' AS DATE) and  a.DateCreated   <= CAST('#to_date#' AS DATE)

This is working fine without any cast of original date time column